# span field error in my css file

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying change the required field validator color in my `ASP.Net MVC` project.

In my form, I have a required field validator like this:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Date" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Date" class="">The Date field is required.</span>
```

The Date field is required.

In my CSS file, I have added,

```
span.field-validation-error {
    color: #b94a48;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But the validation error, color is not reflecting in the browser.
When I try to change the code like this in Inspect element, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
span.field-validation-error > span {
  color: #b94a48;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```